# Changing a label text that is in a separate .xib from main ViewController class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

What I have is a custom table cell created in a separate `.xib`. And with it I have an Objective-C class for this. I made a connection of the label in the custom cell to the  custom cell's class.

In my main .xib I have a `TableView` that the custom cell is added to. The code that does the populating is in the main class (ViewController.m).

So how can I change the `label` in the custom cell from the main class (ViewController.m)?

When the user taps the custom cell, a dialog is shown, and the text of the `label` in the custom cell is changed according to the button selected in the dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured a different approach, and currently I've stopped iOS development, because I hate it, lol

Anyways, thanks guys for replying so quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's a Table Cell, I assume you use it inside a table view. You usually do it via the

```
- (UITableViewCell *)UITableView:(UITableView *) cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"myCustomCell";
    MyCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        for (id anObject in nib) {
            if ([anObject isKindOfClass:[MyCustomCell class]]) {
                cell = (MyCustomCell *)anObject;
            }
        }
    }
    cell.myLabel.text = @"Some Text"; // This will set myLabel text to "Some Text"
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign a tag to the label, i.e. 99 in the Interface builder.
Then, in the ViewController.m, when you hare loading the cell, after loading the xib you can do

```
UILabel *label = [cell viewWithTag: 99];
label.text = @"Some text here... (:";
```

That will do the trick! :)

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty simple :

first create property of your label in your customcell

Customcell.h

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell 

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *yourLabel;
```

now create instance of customcell in your TableViewController

```
YourTableViewController.h
@interface YourTableViewController : UITableViewController<

    {
        CustomCell *cell;
    }
```

and in YourTableViewController.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    cell = (CustomCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];

    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];

        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
                cell =  (CustomCell *) currentObject;
                break;

            }
        }
    }

cell.yourLabel.text = @"whatever you want to add";
```

now , if you want to update label of customcell in other method than just do this.

```
-(void)someMethod()
{
CustomCell *acell = (CustomCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:n];
acell.yourLabel.text = @"whatever you want to add.";
}
```